# Char.IsControl method does not recognize some characters as control

Tags: c#

I noticed that C# 'Char.IsControl' method doesn't recognize some characters as control. For example, the following code outputs false for both values:

```
char pilcrow = '\u00B6';
char softHyphen = '\u00AD';
Console.Write("{0},{1}",char.IsControl(pilcrow), char.IsControl(softHyphen)); // -> 'false,false'
```

Is this an expected behavior? I need to escape such characters in my code.

Comment: I'm 99.9999% sure that if a function like [`char.IsControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iscontrol?view=netframework-4.8#System_Char_IsControl_System_Char_) would contain a bug, it would have been discovered long time ago.

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iscontrol?view=netframework-4.8): "*The Unicode standard assigns code points from \U0000 to \U001F, \U007F, and from \U0080 to \U009F to control characters*". `\u00B6` and `\u00AD` fall outside of this range.

Comment: Those aren't control characters. One is ¶ the other is the [soft hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ad/index.htm), a non-visible character

Comment: Unicode treats `\00B6` as "Other Punctuation", and `\u00AD` as "Format". See [`CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getunicodecategory?view=netframework-4.8#System_Globalization_CharUnicodeInfo_GetUnicodeCategory_System_Char_)

Comment: As for `need to escape such characters in my code` why? .NET Strings are Unicode. You don't need to escape anything and this very question is the proof - SO is an ASP.NET application that stores data in `nvarchar` (Unicode) columns. That's why characters like ²³§¶¤¦°±½¬ can be posted without any special treatment. You'll find many SO questions asking about Chinese or Japanese text that didn't require any special treatment by the SO developers to post. Posters simply posted their text in the question

Comment: I need to escape non-printable characters. Aren't pilcrow and soft hyphen considered as non-printable? And my assumption was that IsControl method shoud have been recognize them.

Comment: @SimonD *why*? This very question proves that you don't. As for non-printable, you *see* the character, don't you? It's not non-printable if it's visible and, well, printable. As for the hyphen, it's used in Word and any other document processor to control word hyphenation (as the name suggests) so there's no problem with printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't control characters. One is the [pilcrow sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b6/index.htm) ¶ which belongs to the `Punctuation, Other [Po]` category , the other is the soft hyphen, a non-visible formatting character that affects how texts gets hyphenated.

There's nothing special about them, in fact you probably use the soft hyphen when writing a paragraph in Word and want to control hyphenation of some words. Word uses ¶ as the paragraph mark - a visualization of a paragraph's end. It doesn't affect formatting, it's just the common way to denote the end of paragraph. In that respect it's no different than ², ³, §, ¶, ¤, ¦, °, ±, ½, ¬ (just holding Right Alt and hitting keys)

.NET strings use Unicode so there's no need to escape these characters. You can just type them directly.

There's no problem with printing either - those characters are used in document processing after all. The soft hyphen controls how the UI or the print engine lays out text during rendering to the screen or paper.

If someone doesn't want those characters to be printed, a simple `string.Remove` will do the job. Re­moving the hyphen can affect how text is printed though, with long words moving to the next line. I added that hyphen to `Removing` in the previous sentence to force hyphenation. Without it, `Removing` would have moved to the next line